# Executing Powershell Command using CMD

Tags: powershell

```
set command=Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -filter "system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='Default Website']/application[@path='/App1']/virtualDirectory[@path='/']" -name "password" -value "%1"

C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Noprofile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command %command%
```

Getting below error

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty : Expected an operator name (eg. 'and')
Input: get-

config("MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST")/system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name=Default Website]/application[@path=/App1]/virtualDirectory[@path=/]
Position: 86
Length: 7
Fragment: Website
At line:1 char:1
```

Comment: There is little to no advantage over invoking PowerShell through `cmd` this way (and a lot of quoting headaches) as opposed to just using the native [`AppCmd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/iis/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-appcmdexe) directly from `cmd`. Either that or use PowerShell throughout; mixing things is a recipe for trouble.

Comment: Is the intent to use the batch file to get around the ExecutionPolicy by using the -ExecutationPolicy Bypass? In that case I typically write all of the logic in a .ps1 file, with the batch file only existing to call the .ps1 file.

If I were to guess, your current error looks like a problem with quoting - try to leave the powershell command all within the call, rather than storing it in a variable first. When in doubt, escape the quotes within the command.

Comment: try `set command=Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath ^'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST^' -filter ^"system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name=^'Default Website^']/application[@path=^'/App1^']/virtualDirectory[@path=^'/^']^" -name ^"password^" -value ^"%1^"` otherwise I do it like kpogue does. Write all PS in a ps1 file, then call it from bat setting the execution policy.

Comment: Thank you, but getting same error